# VBA: I need to save files but if it is repeated, do the sequence "_1, _2, _3, ..." at the end of the file name

Tags: excel, vba, sequence, filenames

My code copy the open workbook and then renames the copied one with the month of analysis, but I need to save all the analysis of the month doing a sequence at the end of the file name. I tried some simple loops and it doesn't work.

```
            Sub NewReport()
            Dim Wb1 As Workbook
            Dim Wb2 As Workbook
            Dim dateStr As String
            Dim myDate As Date
            Dim i As Integer

            With Application
                .ScreenUpdating = False
                .DisplayAlerts = False
                .EnableEvents = False
            End With

            Set Wb1 = ActiveWorkbook

            myDate = Date

            dateStr = Format(myDate, "mmm_yyyy")

            Set Wb2 = Application.Workbooks.Add(1)
            Wb1.Sheets(Array(Wb1.Sheets(1).Name)).Copy Before:=Wb2.Sheets(1)
            Wb2.Sheets(Wb2.Sheets.Count).Delete
            On Error GoTo Fim
            'Wb2.SaveAs Filename:="\\BRGABS001\g_supc\P.C.P\07- Comum\Natalia\3_TESTE_MACRO\" & "Phase_IN_Phase_OUT" & "_" & dateStr, FileFormat:=51

            'Wb2.Close
            With Application
                .ScreenUpdating = True
                .DisplayAlerts = True
                .EnableEvents = True
            End With
        Fim:

        Wb2.SaveAs Filename:="\\BRGABS001\g_supc\P.C.P\07- Comum\Natalia\3_TESTE_MACRO\" & "Phase_IN_Phase_OUT" & "_" & dateStr & "_", FileFormat:=51

        End Sub
```

*UPDATE*

I tried put an "i + 1" and the macro runs until version 2! But at the 3rd I have the same error because the "i" is reseted. I can do the bit at the end for like 50 times assuming that the person don't run the macro 50 times haha. Any suggestions?

```
            Sub NewReport()
            Dim Wb1 As Workbook
            Dim Wb2 As Workbook
            Dim dateStr As String
            Dim myDate As Date

            i = 1

            With Application
                .ScreenUpdating = False
                .DisplayAlerts = False
                .EnableEvents = False
            End With

            Set Wb1 = ActiveWorkbook

            myDate = Date

            dateStr = Format(myDate, "mmm_yyyy")

            Set Wb2 = Application.Workbooks.Add(1)
            Wb1.Sheets(Array(Wb1.Sheets(1).Name)).Copy Before:=Wb2.Sheets(1)
            Wb2.Sheets(Wb2.Sheets.Count).Delete
            On Error GoTo Fim
            Wb2.SaveAs Filename:="\\BRGABS001\g_supc\P.C.P\07- Comum\Natalia\3_TESTE_MACRO\" & "Phase_IN_Phase_OUT" & "_" & dateStr & "_" & i, FileFormat:=51

            'Wb2.Close
            With Application
                .ScreenUpdating = True
                .DisplayAlerts = True
                .EnableEvents = True
            End With

            Fim:
            i = i + 1
            Wb2.SaveAs Filename:="\\BRGABS001\g_supc\P.C.P\07- Comum\Natalia\3_TESTE_MACRO\" & "Phase_IN_Phase_OUT" & "_" & dateStr & "_" & i, FileFormat:=51

        End Sub
```

Comment: "It doesn't work" doesn't tell us anything.  Tell us what actually happens, including any error messages.

Comment: Sorry, it is my first time here. The code runs 1 time, then the error happens because the file with that name already exists:
Run-time error 1004: you cannot save this workbook with the same name as another[...]

Answer (score 1):

After a deep research on google, I found a code and adapt to my situation. It doesn't let to choose the way to save, it's just in the same Folder, but that's ok to me. Credits on the code (I have just put the date at the name):

```
Function FileExist(FilePath As String) As Boolean
'PURPOSE: Test to see if a file exists or not
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com/The-Code-Vault
'RESOURCE: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win003.htm

Dim TestStr As String

'Test File Path (ie "C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\Test\book1.xlsm")
  On Error Resume Next
    TestStr = Dir(FilePath)
  On Error GoTo 0

'Determine if File exists
  If TestStr = "" Then
    FileExist = False
  Else
    FileExist = True
  End If

End Function

Sub SaveNewVersion_Excel()
'PURPOSE: Save file, if already exists add a new version indicator to filename
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com/The-Code-Vault

Dim FolderPath As String
Dim myPath As String
Dim SaveName As String
Dim SaveExt As String
Dim VersionExt As String
Dim Saved As Boolean
Dim x As Long
Dim dateStr As String

myDate = Date

dateStr = Format(myDate, "mmm_yyyy")

TestStr = ""
Saved = False
x = 2

'Version Indicator (change to liking)
  VersionExt = "_" & dateStr & "_Rev"

'Pull info about file
  On Error GoTo NotSavedYet
    myPath = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    myFileName = Mid(myPath, InStrRev(myPath, "\") + 1, InStrRev(myPath, ".") - InStrRev(myPath, "\") - 1)
    FolderPath = Left(myPath, InStrRev(myPath, "\"))
    SaveExt = "." & Right(myPath, Len(myPath) - InStrRev(myPath, "."))
  On Error GoTo 0

'Determine Base File Name
  If InStr(1, myFileName, VersionExt) > 1 Then
    myArray = Split(myFileName, VersionExt)
    SaveName = myArray(0)
  Else
    SaveName = myFileName
  End If

'Test to see if file name already exists
  If FileExist(FolderPath & SaveName & SaveExt) = False Then
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FolderPath & SaveName & SaveExt
    Exit Sub
  End If

'Need a new version made
  Do While Saved = False
    If FileExist(FolderPath & SaveName & VersionExt & x & SaveExt) = False Then
      ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FolderPath & SaveName & VersionExt & x & SaveExt
      Saved = True
    Else
      x = x + 1
    End If
  Loop

'New version saved
  MsgBox "New file version saved (version " & x & ")"

Exit Sub

'Error Handler
NotSavedYet:
  MsgBox "This file has not been initially saved. " & _
    "Cannot save a new version!", vbCritical, "Not Saved To Computer"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

So, the question is how to get from something like:

`\\BRGABS001\g_supc\P.C.P\07- Comum\Natalia\3_TESTE_MACRO\Phase_IN_Phase_OUT_probablySomeString_21`

an incremented value at the end like this one:

`\\BRGABS001\g_supc\P.C.P\07- Comum\Natalia\3_TESTE_MACRO\Phase_IN_Phase_OUT_probablySomeString_22`

This could be carried out through the following steps:

- Take the string and split it by `_`.
- Increment the last part of the string with 1.

---

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim fileName As String
    Dim dateStr As String: dateStr = "probablySomeString"
    Dim i As Long: i = 21

    fileName = "\\BRGABS001\g_supc\P.C.P\07- Comum\" & _
            "Natalia\3_TESTE_MACRO\Phase_IN_Phase_OUT" & "_" & dateStr & "_" & i

    Debug.Print fileName
    Debug.Print Increment(fileName)

End Sub

Public Function Increment(fileName As String) As String

    Dim myResult As String
    Dim newValue As Long
    Dim myArr As Variant

    newValue = Split(fileName, "_")(UBound(Split(fileName, "_"))) + 1
    myArr = Split(fileName, "_")
    myArr(UBound(Split(fileName, "_"))) = newValue
    Increment = Join(myArr, "_")

End Function
```

---

And if the initial file looks like this:

`~omum\Natalia\3_TESTE_MACRO\Phase_IN_Phase_OUT_probablySomeString_21.xlsx` then
 the following sample works:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim fileName As String
    Dim dateStr As String: dateStr = "probablySomeString"
    Dim i As Long: i = 21

    fileName = "\\BRGABS001\g_supc\P.C.P\07- Comum\" & _
            "Natalia\3_TESTE_MACRO\Phase_IN_Phase_OUT" & "_" & dateStr & "_" & i & ".xlsx"

    Debug.Print fileName
    Debug.Print Increment(fileName)

End Sub

Public Function Increment(fileName As String) As String

    Dim myResult As String
    Dim newValue As Long
    Dim myArr As Variant

    newValue = Split(Split(fileName, "_")(UBound(Split(fileName, "_"))), ".")(0) + 1
    myArr = Split(fileName, "_")
    myArr(UBound(Split(fileName, "_"))) = newValue
    Increment = Join(myArr, "_")
    Increment = Increment & ".xslx"

End Function
```

Comment: Nice, it is like mine 
" Wb2.SaveAs Filename:="\\BRGABS001\g_supc\P.C.P\07- Comum\Natalia\3_TESTE_MACRO\" & "Phase_IN_Phase_OUT" & "_" & dateStr & "_", FileFormat:=51"

But it saves the file 12 times, I've already tried something like this... What I need is copy the sheet to a new file with that sequence when I run the macro :/

Comment: @NatáliaRizental - I see. take a look at the edit, the looping is there.

Comment: Isn't it the same thing that te TesteMe()? It saved 12 new versions in a row aswell haha

Comment: @NatáliaRizental - pretty much the same, but it uses your own code.

Comment: I used mine but it repeated the file 12 times asweel, as I don't want to happen haha. Take a look at the my edit on the question, I solved a little bit the problem haha

Comment: @NatáliaRizental - I think I have understood where the problem is. See the updated answer.

Comment: @NatáliaRizental - where did you take this code from? In my answer I do not have `Split(fileName, "")` . And the inverted commas look a bit different.

Comment: "Error 9: Subscript out of range" on the two "newValues"

Comment: @NatáliaRizental - you have copied and pasted my code and it gives error?

Comment: It is the same of your code on  my VBA! But still not fine )=

Comment: @NatáliaRizental - this is really strange. What happens if you close all your excel files, open a completely new one add one of the two pieces in a new module and run it again? Run this one `TestMe` only.

Comment: Just copy and paste of you code in a new workbook? What happens is: nothing, because no file is being created

Comment: @NatáliaRizental - the idea of the code is to show how to make from a string like this `~blySomeString_21.xlsx` the string `~blySomeString_22.xlsx`. No file is needed.

Comment: I couldn't adapt it to my code, but I found another solution!